# phonegap jquerymobile app taking lot of memory

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I build a phonegap jquerymobile application for Android with one start page.My start                  page(Its Given below) is very simple with one line content.After installing it in the device  ,everytime i am starting the app  the memory taken by the app is getting increased consistently & making the functionalities work slow.Can anybody please help me to fix this problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
       <head>
          <title>PhoneGap</title>
          <meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height,width=device-width,initial-  scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0" />
          <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
       </head>
       <body>
          <div data-role="page" id="indexpage">
             <div data-role="header" id="indexheader" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
                <div id="shoppinglistname"
             </div>
             <div data-role="content" id="divcontent">
                Content here 
             </div>
          </div>
          </div>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: close <div id="shoppinglistname" first...

Answer (score 0):

Basically, You are loading web pages in android web browser. Definitely it takes memory. For that, i used to clear cache memory every time of application starts.
Use this code before load url,

```
super.clearCache();
```